# Using a product identifier across applications

Tags: ios

I have two applications in my developer account. Is it possible to use product identifier of one application with another without duplicating it? Or product identifiers are specific to an application?

Comment: What has this got to do with In-App Purchase?

Comment: I have an application in which in-app purchasing is configured. i want to use same product identifiers for another app

Comment: But that has little to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Product identifier is unique across the developer account. We can't use same product identifier for multiple apps of same developer account. But you can use 2 different product identifiers with same name in 2 different developer accounts. But it can not be possible to have the same in different apps of same Developer account.